# Creating an empty line

Tags: echo

I'm currently trying to add an empty line in here, the example of the command that I have so far

```
echo -e "my kernel version is $(uname -a) \nand the current date is $(date)"
```

how do I change the whole thing, so the output of this is

```
my kernel version is Linux centos7 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Sun Jul 26 15:27:06 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
*** empty line***   
and the current date is Fri Apr 23 09:18:29 EEST 2021
```

Comment: `echo -e "... \n\n..."`; see also [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/72456)

Comment: A "blank line" is nothing more than a line that immediately ends in another '\n'; Same as pressing \[RETURN]/\[ENTER] _twice_ in a text editor creates a blank line. So '\n\n' creates a blank line at that point.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a here-document to output the multi-line message (the empty line is created by including an empty line in the here-document):

```bsh
cat <<END
my kernel version is $(uname -a)

and the current date is $(date)
END
```

This uses `printf` to output the message (the empty line is created by outputting two consecutive newlines):

```bsh
printf 'my kernel version is %s\n\nand the current date is %s\n' "$(uname -a)" "$(date)"
```

On my system, both of these produce the text

```
my kernel version is OpenBSD box.prefix.example.com 6.9 GENERIC.MP#473 amd64

and the current date is Fri Apr 23 17:03:24 CEST 2021
```

See also: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that `printf` is more versatile than `echo`, but a quick modification is:

FROM:

```
echo -e "my kernel version is $(uname -a) \nand the current date is $(date)"
```

TO:

```
echo -e "my kernel version is $(uname -a) \n\nand the current date is $(date)"
```

Feel free to add as many *newlines* `\n` as you like for more white space.